# Republishing an existing map service with the same name without stopping the old one?

Tags: arcgis-server, map-service, publishing, mosaic-dataset

Please, consider the following scenario:

1. The following mosaic dataset contains 3 images in it, it was published as a service and cashed, and it works fine and many organizations read from my server.

[image]

2. I need to add 2 more images to the same mosaic dataset, so the shape of the new  published service will be similar to the screenshot below.

   [image]

Now my question is what is the best practice to update the old published service such that the new one reflects the change in the mosaic dataset and shows the 5 images?

Note that I want to publish it with the same name in order not to interrupt the other organizations “not to change the link to this service in their web mapping applications”.

Answer (score 2):

Before doing **ANY** of this, be sure to make backups of your data in the event something goes awry .

What we have done in similar situations is publish the new service with a different name.  Once published, we cache the new service.  Once the caching process completes for the new service, we rename the cache folders for the services in the arcgiscache directory:

```
LocationOfArcGISServerInstallation -> arcgisserver -> directories -> arcgiscache.
```

So, say the original service is called MOSAICS.  We publish a new one called MOSAICS_temp.  We then cache MOSACIS_temp with the same levels/resolutions as MOSAICS (**VERY IMPORTANT!**).  Once the caching is complete, we rename the cache directory like so:

```
Old Name              New Name

MOSAICS               MOSAICS_old
MOSAICS_temp          MOSAICS
```

The service is never turned off, and the cache points to the updated output.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Many thanks Ew_gis,  I will test this method and keep you posted, but what about the service name " which is displayed in the ArcGIS " which is in my case "Orthophoto_WestBank_2006_50cm_TMGrid_jpg02 " does it change too??

Comment: No, the service will be the same as the name you used to publish the Map Service Definition File.  Changing the cache directory name does not rename any part of the MSD.

Comment: very appreciated for your help, but I need to change the service name "MOSAICS_temp to MOSAICS for example" such that no interruption will happen to other users, my problem isnt only with the cached folder, is their any methods to change the NEW service name  with the OLD one? if that is possible the issue will be solved I think.

Comment: If your service is only used as a cache, meaning you do not use any of the layers for feature service operations, then you do not need to rename your MOSAIC service.  Granted, your service will not list the new mosaics, but the cache will draw them.  Frankly, once a service is cached, the only thing that matters are {X}/{Y}/{Z} properties of a tile when the service renders.  There are no longer "layers" to account for.  I'll admit, my answer is a bit hacky, but unfortunately I do not see another way to update the display of a cached service without restarting and recaching the original.